# How to set Session Variable in C# Using ContentUpdate

Tags: c#, iphone, asp.net, session

Well, the question seems very straightforward, but it isn't.

I want to set a session variable like the following:

```
Session["mySession"] = "Some Value";
```

But I want to do so when clicking on a button, and using `ContentUpdate`:

```
protected void myButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["mySession"] = "Some Value";
}
```

and

```
<asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" OnClick="myButtonClick" />
```

Ok, so far so good. It works, and it has always worked. Now let's talk about the problem.

The only way I can get it working on an iPhone is to set session variable is on the Page_Load function. It works when browsing from my computer.

So, I guess my question is:

How to set a Session Variable in C# Using `ContentUpdate` on an Iphone?

Comment: HTTP doesn't differ between PC and iPhone.  What do you mean you can't change the session values after page load?  Are you getting an exception or are you thinking that values are not set?

Comment: Thank you for answering. I don't get any exceptions, no errors, but when I try to retrieve whatever is in the session, it comes null, as if it was never set. BUT THAT HAPPENS ONLY WHEN I RUN ON THE IPHONE, when I run on the PC it works just perfectly.

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you using some sort of framework to allow you to develop code for the iPhone using C#? Typically, you'd use Objective-C to do so. Or are you saying your browsing your ASP.NET site with Safari on an iPhone?

Comment: I did some testing, and if I set the session on the Page_Load, it works, but when I try to set the session using ContentUpdate, it doesnt work. It is like if the session was not updated or refreshed. I dont know.

Comment: I am using ASPX and C#, nothing else. A normal webpage.

Comment: And of course, ScriptManager and UpdatePanel.

Comment: What is <ContentUpdate>  Do you mean ContentTemplate?

Comment: I meant <asp:UpdatePanel>

Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you checked your iphone is accepting cookies?
-i know you are using session but a cookie is needed to estabish a session.

Comment: We solved the problem a long while ago, but what you mentioned was actually the problem at the time. I'm setting your answer as the right answer then! :)

Answer (score -1):

I found a way around the problem, not the solution I wanted, but it worked for what I needed.

I was using the `Session[]` variable and found out about the `Application[]` variable and switch them... tadaaa... it worked!

Does anybody know why, and could share their knowledge?

Thank you for the comments posted.

Comment: Session[] is unique for each client session. Application[] is global to all clients.